# How should I identify relative blocks and change them to absolute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, position

How should I identify relative blocks and change them to absolute position but in the same place.

It can be programmed by javascript or jquery? Or actualli it's not possible?

Thanks you very much.

Comment: What do you mean by a "relative block"?  Please be much more specific about what you're trying to accomplish and why.

Comment: When i say "relative block" I mean "div or p that have position:relative on css"

Comment: If you add `.relative{position:relative;}` to your CSS and then position anything relative by adding that class to the element then you can easily get them all by `$('.relative')`. Otherwise you would probably have to iterate through *all* the elements on the page and check it's `.css('position')` to see if it's relative, which I don't recommend...

Comment: I didn't mean that. I have page with some relative divs. I want to get them on jquery and change them to absolute, but still to be at the same place.

Comment: @user3618978 - can you explain why you're trying to do this so we can perhaps offer easier or more practical ways to solve your problem.

Comment: Changing every relatively positioned div to absolute will turn most web pages into a jumbled mess. It's almost certainly not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

CSS

```
.relative
{position:relative;
}
.absolute
{position:absolute;
}
```

JQUERY

```
$('class/id').click(function() {
$('div').removeClass().addClass('absolute');


});
```

But if you do this the position of all `div` start from the top left corner depending on the parent div. I dont think you need to do this for all the elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you're changing only specific divs to `position:absolute` your best option would be to do something such as this:

```
<div class="relative"></div>
<div class="relative absolute"></div>
<div class="relative"></div>

.relative {
position: relative;
}

.relative.absolute {
position: absolute;
}
```

If they need to be set `absolute` onload depending on whatever then you could append the `.absolute` class using `addClass()` jQuery function.

I hope I haven't misunderstood your question there, if I have please ignore the answer.